# How do I solve the modal update issues in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, updates

I have a modal in which I want to update my `Question` but the modal keeps updating the same question so can someone help me because my modal keeps taking the same `$id` even if I click on different entries.

This is my `QuestionController`

```
 public function update($questionId)
    { 
      $this->validate(request(),[

        'label' => 'required',


      ]);

      $data = request()->all();

      $question = Question::find($questionId);
      $question->label = $data['label'];

      $question->save();

      return redirect('/question');
    }
```

this is my `Modal` in the `blade.php` file

```
 <!-- Modal Edit -->
    <div class="modal" id="editMcqModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="editMcqModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenteredLabel">Edit Question</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="" action="/question/{{$question->id}}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PATCH')


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="label" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter Question" cols="5"
                                row="15">{{$question->label}}</textarea>
                        </div>

                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-success float-right">Update
                                Question</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                    

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: put dd($questionId) in your controller for different  questions if it gives you a different id every time then there is nothing wrong else check your method which makes the question balde

Comment: where are you clicking from to open the modal? how are you passing the custom data  into the modal? usually, custom attributes are put on the element that you're clicking to open the modal.